# iPhone randomly loses service

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

I have an iPhone X which from time to time looses service. Sometimes restart helps, but not always (then the only solution is to wait). In a service they cleaned what they could, and the phone looses the connection less often (but it might be my illusion)
What could be the issue here?

Comment: With „loose service“ you mean a lost carrier signal? SIM card might be broken, can you try a replacement from your carrier (or borrow a SIM card from a friend to see if makes any difference)?